# Converting Image into Byte Array gives Null Exception

Tags: vb.net

When i try to convert Image into Byte Array its gives me Null Exception. I am  splitting image into 4 equal part and then converting each part into Byte Array.

```
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    i = Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

    Dim g As Graphics
    Dim OriginalBit As New Bitmap(i)
    Dim x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x, y, k As Integer
    x = i.Width / 2
    y = i.Height / 2
    Dim i1, i2, i3, i4 As Image
    Dim bit As Bitmap = OriginalBit.Clone(New RectangleF(0, 0, x, y), Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare)
    PictureBox2.Width = bit.Width
    PictureBox2.Height = bit.Height
    i1 = bit
```

[image]

But when i assign Split-ted Bitmapimage object(bit) which carry the split-ed image to Imageobject (i1)and try to convert it to Byte Array it gives me error.

Comment: Put your mouse cursor on `i1`, it is probably null (Nothing in VB.net)

Comment: @codingbiz yes i know but why.I am assigning bitmap object to i1.

Comment: Perhaps the answer is in the code before the `i4=bit` line, but this code is not visible in your post

Comment: think i4=bit  as i1=bit and everything else is above the image

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the exception I have noticed: `Parameter name: encoder`.

So I suppose that something is wrong in `i1.RawFormat` not in the i1 itself.
Probably the clipping operation or the `Clone(....,Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare)` leave the bit object without a RawFormat value correctly set.

I can't test now, but I will try with

```
Dim bit As Bitmap = OriginalBit.Clone(New RectangleF(0, 0, x, y), OriginalBit.PixelFormat)
```

or

```
i1.Save(mem, OriginalBit.RawFormat)
```

Comment: But you can confirm that `i1` is not null?